# WCF: How to connect to SQL Server using Windows Authentication?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wcf

A SilverLight application is making a call to a WCF service and trying to execute a stored procedure in my SQL Server database using Linq-to-SQL.

```
Connection string ="Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;Connect Timeout=30000"
```

I get an error:

> Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.
>   Exception Number: 18452

Comment: What user are you expecting to make the call? The AppPool user?

Comment: I am using IIS5.1.Under Default Website ,Inisde Anonymous access i have given my window id and password.

Comment: I assume the SQL server is on a different machine? Is the machine you are running the IIS on trusted for delegation in your domain?

Comment: So if you follow the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245336/soaphttpclientprotocol-readresponse-the-request-failed-with-http-status-401-u/11248883#11248883 the error still occurs?